# How can I make a time parsing predicate work in both directions?

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

Using SWI-Prolog I have made this simple predicate that relates a time that is in `hh:mm` format into a time term.

```
time_string(time(H,M), String) :-
    number_string(H,Hour),
    number_string(M,Min),
    string_concat(Hour,":",S),
    string_concat(S,Min,String).
```

The predicate though can only work in one direction.

```
time_string(time(10,30),String).
String = "10:30".      % This is perfect.
```

Unfortunately this query fails.

```
time_string(Time,"10:30").
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] number_string(_8690,_8692)
ERROR:   [10] time_string(time(_8722,_8724),"10:30") at /tmp/prolcompDJBcEE.pl:74
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /usr/local/logic/lib/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1107
```

It would be really nice if I didn't have to write a whole new predicate to answer this query. Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, going from the structured term `time(H,M)` to the string `String` *is* easier than going from the unstructured `String` the term `time(H,M)`.

Your predicate works in the "generation" direction.

For the other direction, you want to *parse* the `String`. In this case, this is computationally easy and can be done without search/backtracking, which is nice!

Use Prolog's ["Definite Clause Grammar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) syntax which are "just" a nice way to write predicates that process a "list of stuff". In this case the list of stuff is a list of characters (atoms of length 1). (For the relevant page from SWI-Prolog, see [here](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG))

With some luck, the DCG code can run backwards/forwards, but this is generally not the case. Real code meeting some demands of efficiency or causality may force it so that under the hood of a single predicate, you first branch by "processing direction", and then run through rather different code structures to deliver the goods.

So here. The code immediately "decays" into the parse and generate branches. Prolog does not yet manage to behave fully constraint-based. You just *have* to do some things before others.

Anyway, let's do this:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

% ---
% "Generate" direction; note that String may be bound to something
% in which case this clause also verifies whether generating "HH:MM"
% from time(H,M) indeed yields (whatever is denoted by) String.
% ---

process_time(time(H,M),String) :-
   integer(H),                            % Demand that H,M are valid integers inside limits
   integer(M),
   between(0,23,H),
   between(0,59,M),
   !,                                     % Guard passed, commit to this code branch
   phrase(time_g(H,M),Chars,[]),          % Build Codes from time/2 Term
   string_chars(String,Chars).            % Merge Codes into a string, unify with String

% ---
% "Parse" direction. 
% ---

process_time(time(H,M),String) :-
   string(String),                        % Demand that String be a valid string; no demands on H,M  
   !,                                     % Guard passed, commit to this code branch
   string_chars(String,Chars),            % Explode String into characters
   phrase(time_p(H,M),Chars,[]).          % Parse "Codes" into H and M

% ---
% "Generate" DCG
% ---
   
time_g(H,M) --> hour_g(H), [':'], minute_g(M).
hour_g(H)   --> { divmod(H,10,V1,V2), digit_int(D1,V1), digit_int(D2,V2) }, digit(D1), digit(D2).
minute_g(M) --> { divmod(M,10,V1,V2), digit_int(D1,V1), digit_int(D2,V2) }, digit(D1), digit(D2).

% ---
% "Parse" DCG
% ---
   
time_p(H,M) --> hour_p(H), [':'], minute_p(M).
hour_p(H)   --> digit(D1), digit(D2), { digit_int(D1,V1), digit_int(D2,V2), H is V1*10+V2, between(0,23,H) }.
minute_p(M) --> digit(D1), digit(D2), { digit_int(D1,V1), digit_int(D2,V2), M is V1*10+V2, between(0,59,M) }.   
   
% ---
% Do I really have to code this? Oh well!
% ---

digit_int('0',0).
digit_int('1',1).
digit_int('2',2).
digit_int('3',3).
digit_int('4',4).
digit_int('5',5).
digit_int('6',6).
digit_int('7',7).
digit_int('8',8).
digit_int('9',9).

% ---
% Let's add plunit tests!
% ---

:- begin_tests(hhmm).

test("parse 1",    true(T == time(0,0)))   :- process_time(T,"00:00").
test("parse 2",    true(T == time(12,13))) :- process_time(T,"12:13").
test("parse 1",    true(T == time(23,59))) :- process_time(T,"23:59").
test("generate",   true(S == "12:13"))     :- process_time(time(12,13),S).
test("verify",     true)                   :- process_time(time(12,13),"12:13").
test("complete",   true(H == 12))          :- process_time(time(H,13),"12:13").

test("bad parse",    fail)                 :- process_time(_,"66:66").
test("bad generate", fail)                 :- process_time(time(66,66),_).

:- end_tests(hhmm).
```

That's a lot of code.

Does it work?

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: hhmm ........ done
% All 8 tests passed
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the simplicity of the pattern, a DCG could be deemeed overkill, but actually it provides us an easy access to the atomics ingredients that we can feed into some declarative arithmetic library. For instance

```erlang
:- module(hh_mm_bi,
         [hh_mm_bi/2
         ,hh_mm_bi//1
         ]).

:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

hh_mm_bi(T,S) :- phrase(hh_mm_bi(T),S).

hh_mm_bi(time(H,M)) --> n2(H,23),":",n2(M,59).
n2(V,U)             --> d(A),d(B), {V#=A*10+B,V#>=0,V#=<U}.
d(V)                --> digit(D), {V#=D-0'0}.
```

Some tests

```erlang
?- hh_mm_bi(T,`23:30`).
T = time(23, 30).

?- hh_mm_bi(T,`24:30`).
false.

?- phrase(hh_mm_bi(T),S).
T = time(0, 0),
S = [48, 48, 58, 48, 48] ;
T = time(0, 1),
S = [48, 48, 58, 48, 49] ;
...
```

*edit*

library(clpfd) is not the only choice we have for declarative arithmetic. Here is another shot, using [`library(clpBNR)`](https://github.com/ridgeworks/clpBNR_pl), but it requires you install the appropriate pack, using `?- pack_install(clpBNR).` After this is done, another solution functionally equivalent to the one above could be

```erlang
:- module(hh_mm_bnr,
         [hh_mm_bnr/2
         ,hh_mm_bnr//1
         ]).

:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
:- use_module(library(clpBNR)).

hh_mm_bnr(T,S) :- phrase(hh_mm_bnr(T),S).

hh_mm_bnr(time(H,M)) --> n2(H,23),":",n2(M,59).
n2(V,U)              --> d(A),d(B), {V::integer(0,U),{V==A*10+B}}.
d(V)                 --> digit(D), {{V==D-0'0}}.
```

*edit*

The comment (now removed) by @DavidTonhofer has made me think that a far simpler approach is available, moving the 'generation power' into d//1:

```erlang
:- module(hh_mm,
         [hh_mm/2
         ,hh_mm//1
         ]).

hh_mm(T,S) :- phrase(hh_mm(T),S).

hh_mm(time(H,M)) --> n2(H,23),":",n2(M,59).
n2(V,U)          --> d(A),d(B), { V is A*10+B, V>=0, V=<U }.
d(V)             --> [C], { member(V,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), C is V+0'0 }.
```

Comment: CLP brings so much to the table it's amazing.

Comment: Cool 3rd solution. One can see the tradeoff of "Keep code not-searching on a deterministic path through state space (polynomial or linear cost) with bespoke pieces of code" vs "Let code search (potentially exponential cost or higher polynomial cost) but use generic code".

Comment: (I removed the comment because I wrongly said "parsing" instead of generation)

Comment: Instead of `member/2` one can also use `between(0,9,V)` for great brevity!

Answer (score 0):

```
time_string(time(H,M),String)
:-
hour(H) ,
minute(M) ,
number_string(H,Hs) ,
number_string(M,Ms) ,
string_concat(Hs,":",S) ,
string_concat(S,Ms,String)
.

hour(H) :- between(0,11,H) .

minute(M) :- between(0,59,M) .
```

```
/*
?- time_string(time(10,30),B).
B = "10:30".

?- time_string(time(H,M),"10:30").
H = 10,
M = 30 ;
false.

?- time_string(time(H,M),S).
H = M, M = 0,
S = "0:0" ;
H = 0,
M = 1,
S = "0:1" ;
H = 0,
M = 2,
S = "0:2" ;
H = 0,
M = 3,
S = "0:3" %etc.
*/
```

Comment: Works (barring some tuning on fixing a prefix 0) but will take 12*60 attempts to parse 11:59 .

Comment: on my system the call for time(11,59) takes .0000005 seconds .

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer, avoiding DCGs as overkill for this task. Or rather, the two separate tasks involved here: Not every relation can be expressed in a single Prolog predicate, especially not every relation on something as extra-logical as SWI-Prolog's strings.

So here is the solution for one of the tasks, computing strings from times (this is your code renamed):

```
time_string_(time(H,M), String) :-
    number_string(H,Hour),
    number_string(M,Min),
    string_concat(Hour,":",S),
    string_concat(S,Min,String).
```

For example:

```
?- time_string_(time(11, 59), String).
String = "11:59".
```

Here is a simple implementation of the opposite transformation:

```
string_time_(String, time(H, M)) :-
    split_string(String, ":", "", [Hour, Minute]),
    number_string(H, Hour),
    number_string(M, Minute).
```

For example:

```
?- string_time_("11:59", Time).
Time = time(11, 59).
```

And here is a predicate that chooses which of these transformations to use, depending on which arguments are known. The exact condition will depend on the cases that can occur in your application, but it seems reasonable to say that if the string is indeed a string, we want to try to parse it:

```
time_string(Time, String) :-
    (   string(String)
    ->  % Try to parse the existing string.
        string_time_(String, Time)
    ;   % Hope that Time is a valid time term.
        time_string_(Time, String) ).
```

This will translate both ways:

```
?- time_string(time(11, 59), String).
String = "11:59".

?- time_string(Time, "11:59").
Time = time(11, 59).
```